# How to combine these 'for' statements?

Tags: python, operating-system

I'm writing a program that can scan root folder, directories and files and rename them so they all fit a naming convention.

I currently have 3 `for` loops, one for root, dirs, files, and then I apply the `os.rename()` and `.replace()` method so change the file names. The code looks like this:

```
    def rename_files(self):
        """ Handles the renaming of files """

        for root, dirs, files in os.walk(self._path_start):
            for _r in root:
                # Show original file name
                print(_r)
                try:
                    os.rename(_r, _r.replace(" ", "-").lower())
                except Exception:
                    pass

                try:
                    os.rename(_r, _r.replace("_", "-").lower())
                except Exception:
                    pass
                print(f"File renamed: {_r}")

            for _d in dirs:
                # Show original file name
                print(_d)
                try:
                    os.rename(_d, _d.replace(" ", "-").lower())
                except Exception:
                    pass

                try:
                    os.rename(_d, _d.replace("_", "-").lower())
                except Exception:
                    pass
                print(f"File renamed: {_d}")

            for file in files:
                # Show original file name
                print(file)
                try:
                    os.rename(file, file.replace(" ", "-").lower())
                except Exception:
                    pass

                try:
                    os.rename(file, file.replace("_", "-").lower())
                except Exception:
                    pass
                print(f"File renamed: {file}")
```

I'm aware there will be issues with my code, and that exceptions shouldnt be handled like that from what I've read, but I'm wondering if someone could help me make the above more concise? or I am open to re-writing the section a new way entirely if anyone has a suggestion?

Ideally, I'd like to be able to blend the 3 seperate `for` statements and then apply `os.rename()` and `.replace()` once, rather than 3 times but I've not been able to get anything to work.

Comment: don't think there is much to change about loops except You could do this: `os.rename(_r, _r.replace(" ", "-").replace('_', '-').lower()` therefore reducing each code block to only one `try/except`, oh and usually don't just except every exception and pass it, You should either print what exception was raised or except a specific exception

Comment: @Matiiss Thanks for the reply! Reducing the code block was the kind of help I was after too so thanks for that.  About `try/except`, I did read that elsewhere too. Thanks man.

Comment: actually I didn't write this but had a thought that it would be possible to maybe put a for loop in a function and pass arguments therefore even more reducing the code

Answer (score 0):

The code will fail as soon as it makes the first rename, causing all other yields from os.walk to be different. The code can get very complex and heavy on the cpu but I think the best solution is to start with the dirs and to recreate os.walk generator on every change with a while loop and then to change the actual files.

More optimization may be added but a sample code would look like this(not tested):

```
def rename_files(self):
    """ Handles the renaming of files """
    breaker=True
    while breaker:
        for root, dirs, files in os.walk(self._path_start):
            # Show original file name
            print(root,dirs,files)
            for dir in dirs:
                if " " in dir or "_" in dir:
                    dir_path=os.path.join(root,dir)
                    os.rename(dir_path,dir_path.replace(" ", "-").replace("_","-").lower())
                    break
                break
            for file in files:
                if " " in file or "_" in file:
                    file_path=os.path.join(root,file)
                    os.rename(file_path,file_path.replace(" ", "-").replace("_","-").lower())
                    print(f"File renamed: {file}") 
                breaker=False
        continue
```